# Couldn't Order by ASC or DESC inside "case when" in postgresql, JPQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, sql-order-by, jpql

Here is the JPQL query for postgresql database where 'priceSortOrder' and 'currentMarketPrice' are parameters. currentMarketPrice is an integer value. priceSortOrder can be 'ASC' or 'DESC'.

```
select product
from tms.product

order by (case (:priceSortOrder)
when NULL then 1
when 'ASC' then case
when product.exchange_Rate_Type = 'FIXED_RATE' then product.fixed_Rate
else (:currentMarketPrice) end
when 'DESC' then case
when product.exchange_Rate_Type = 'FIXED_RATE' then product.fixed_Rate
else (:currentMarketPrice) end end) DESC
```

I can run the query well. But it doesn't serve my purpose. As, I want to sort it based on priceSortOrder. But, adding ASC or DESC inside when like below gives the syntax error (ELSE, END or WHEN expected, got 'ASC'). I can add hardcode 'ASC' or 'DESC' at the very end only and thus always sorted in descending order.

Error code: (But explains my purpose)

```
select product
from tms.product

order by (case (:priceSortOrder)
when NULL then 1
when 'ASC' then case
when product.exchange_Rate_Type = 'FIXED_RATE' then product.fixed_Rate
else (:currentMarketPrice) ASC end
when 'DESC' then case
when product.exchange_Rate_Type = 'FIXED_RATE' then product.fixed_Rate
else (:currentMarketPrice) end DESC end)
```

What can I do to get my expected output?

Comment: Case statements can only be used in expressions. ASC and DESC are not part of the ORDER BY's expression, but part of the STATEMENT, like 'SELECT'  or 'FROM', so you can't change them dynamically.

Comment: When sorting by a numeric expression use minus (`-product.fixed Rate`) for the case you want descending order.

Answer (score 0):

As an example to have different directions in the ORDER BY clause of your SQL Statement, you can use the following code :

```
DECLARE @ORDER_DIRECTION BIT = 1;

SELECT * FROM S_PRS.T_PERSONNE_PHYSIQUE_PSP 
ORDER BY COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(@ORDER_DIRECTION, 1) AS VARCHAR(1)), PSP_NOM) ASC,
         COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(@ORDER_DIRECTION, 0) AS VARCHAR(1)), PSP_NOM) DESC;
```

Another ways is :

```
SELECT * FROM S_PRS.T_PERSONNE_PHYSIQUE_PSP 
ORDER BY iif(@ORDER_DIRECTION = 1, PSP_NOM, NULL) DESC,
         iif(@ORDER_DIRECTION = 0, NULL, PSP_NOM) ASC;
```

When @ORDER_DIRECTION = 1 the order is ASC, when 0 DESC for the PSP_NOM (person's name) column.